# How to create multiple columns in r dataframe by implementing some query conditions

Tags: r

I have a dataset which is similar to the following:

```
Age    Food_1_1 Food_1_2 Food_1_3  Amount_1_1 Amount_1_2 Amount_1_3
6-9        a        b          a      2          3           4
6-9        b        b          c      1          2           3
6-9                 c          a                 4           1
9-10       c        c          b      1          3           1
9-10       c        a          b      1          2           1
```

Using R, I want to get the following data set which contains new set of columns a, b and c by adding the corresponding values:

Age    Food_1_1 Food_1_2 Food_1_3  Amount_1_1 Amount_1_2 Amount_1_3   a   b   c
 6-9          a        b        a      2          3           4        6   3   0
 6-9          b        b        c      1          2           3        0   3   3
 6-9                   c        a                 4           1        1   0   4
 9-10         c        c        b      1          3           1        0   1   4
 9-10         c        a        b      1          2           1        2   1   1

Note: My data also contains missing values. The variables Monday:Wednesday are factors and the variables Value1:Value3 are numeric. For more clearity: 1st row of column "a" contains the addition of all values through Value1 to Value3 related to a (say for example 2+4 =6).

Answer (score 1):

One way using base R:

```
data$id <- 1:nrow(data)  # Create a unique id
vlist <- list(grep("day$", names(data)), grep("^Value", names(data)))
d1 <- reshape(data, direction="long", varying=vlist, v.names=c("Day","Value"))
d2 <- aggregate(Value~id+Day, FUN=sum, na.rm=TRUE, data=d1)
d3 <- reshape(d2, direction="wide", v.names="Value", timevar="Day")
d3[is.na(d3)] <- 0
merge(data, d3, by="id", all.x=TRUE)

#  id  Age Monday Tuesday Wednesday Value1 Value2 Value3 Value.a Value.b Value.c
#1  1  6-9      a       b         a      2      3      4       6       3       0
#2  2  6-9      b       b         c      1      2      3       0       3       3
#3  3  6-9   <NA>       c         a     NA      4      1       1       0       4
#4  4 9-10      c       c         b      1      3      1       0       1       4
#5  5 9-10      c       a         b      1      2      1       2       1       1
```

---

**Data**:

```
data <- structure(list(Age = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("6-9", 
"9-10"), class = "factor"), Monday = structure(c(1L, 2L, NA, 
3L, 3L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), Tuesday = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), 
    Wednesday = structure(c(1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("a", 
    "b", "c"), class = "factor"), Value1 = c(2L, 1L, NA, 1L, 
    1L), Value2 = c(3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L), Value3 = c(4L, 3L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: For some reason when I am running d1, it is giving me error. Like : Error in attr(rval, "reshapeLong") <- undoInfo : 
  attempt to set an attribute on NULL. Also, can you please clarify what does this v.names=c("Day","Value") represent.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide some data using `dput`. It can be a small subset of the whole data.

Comment: `v.names=c("Day","Value")` determines the names of the reshaped columns in long form.

Comment: Thanks. When I tried vlist for the first time, I got two lists [[1]] 2 3 4 & [[2]]  5  6 7. However, when I am trying to run for the second time, I got [[1]] integer(0) and [[2]] 5 6 7. Also, for some reason, from d1 to remaining code did not run.

Comment: Second time? I don't understand. Did you change anything? `vlist` should be a list with two components. The first component contains the indices of your "days", the second the indices of your "Values". Your data must contain the days of the week (Monday, Tuesday...) and the corresponding values (Value1, Value2...). If not, then the code would need to be modified.

Comment: If the code doesn't work for your real data, then your real data is not _similar_ to your toy example data provided in the question. The names must be similar. At least the days of the week must contain the word "day" at the end and the Values columns start with "Value".

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Second time means, I change day$ in the vlist and then run to check what happen. Though, I changed it back to day$, but it is giving the same results.

Comment: What should I do if I have different columns name instead of the name of Week days. The names could be something else like: Food_1, Food_2,...Food_10. The variables Values are the corresponding numeric values associated with the previous variables.

Comment: use `grep` to find the indices. For example: `grep("^Food", names(data))` will return the indices of all the columns that start with "Food". Try to learn the basic regex. It can help a lot.

Comment: Thank you. However, I am still getting an error message of following type:Error in reshapeLong(data, idvar = idvar, timevar = timevar, varying = varying,  : 
  'varying' arguments must be the same length , when I am running  d1 <- reshape(data, direction="long", varying=vlist, v.names=c("Food","Value")).

Comment: Something is weird then. You'll have to `dput` the data so I can see what's the problem

Comment: I am also getting the same error for the data, I have posted here. I used the code "d1 <- reshape(data, direction="long", varying=vlist, v.names=c("Day","Value"))". The error message is like "Error in reshapeLong(data, idvar = idvar, timevar = timevar, varying = varying,  :  'varying' arguments must be the same length".

Comment: I can't help unless you provide the data. Edit your question and show the output of `dput` like I did. Or use the data I provided, which looks like yours, and try to find the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code:

```
data[] <- lapply(data, as.character)
data$rownumber<-rownames(data)
x<-gather(data[,c(1:4,8)], Day, Letter, Monday:Wednesday) %>% mutate(row2 = rownames(x))
y<-gather(data[,c(1,5:7,8)], Day, Value, Value1:Value3)%>% mutate(row2 = rownames(y))
z<-left_join(x, y, by =c("Age","rownumber", "row2")) %>% group_by(Age, rownumber, Letter) %>% dplyr::summarise(suma = sum(as.numeric(Value), na.rm = T)) %>% mutate(suma = replace_na(suma, 0))

z<-dcast(z, rownumber ~ Letter , value.var="suma") %>% left_join(data, z, by  = "rownumber")
z$Var.2<-NULL
z[is.na(z)]<-0
```

Output:

```
  rownumber a b c  Age Monday Tuesday Wednesday Value1 Value2 Value3
1         1 6 3 0  6-9      a       b         a      2      3      4
2         2 0 3 3  6-9      b       b         c      1      2      3
3         3 1 0 4  6-9              c         a      0      4      1
4         4 0 1 4 9-10      c       c         b      1      3      1
5         5 2 1 1 9-10      c       a         b      1      2      1
```

Comment: When I am trying to build the z dataset, I am getting an error like Error: `by` can't contain join column `rownumber` which is missing from LHS
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.